# cant find js and css resources - get 404

Tags: jsp, web-applications

i have a very simple webapp and cannot get .js and .css files from the server by `<script>` and `<link>` tags. 
error: `GET http://localhost:8080/resources/js/lib.js 404 (Not Found)`

this is my index.jsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <jsp:include page="/pages/general/scripts.jsp"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

this is scripts.jsp:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/lib.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css">
```

my files:

[image]

what am i doing wrong here?

EDIT: btw, i checked and i can easily reach the files by their url. if i access localhost:8080/myApp/resources/js/lib.js then i see the file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/lib.js"></script>
```

I suspect path is not proper. Try something like **src="./resources/js/lib.js"**